# HTTP_REFERER detract only toplevel doamin how it?

Tags: php, http-referer

i need to use

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if($ref !== 'http://hi.com')
```

have is problem is if traffic come from http://hi.com/something condition become not true.
how to test only top level domain ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of **`strpos()`** here

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(strpos($ref,'http://hi.com'))
{
echo "found";
}
```